# Adding a class to a button, when button has specific value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Is it possible to add a class to a button that already has a class whenever the value of the button changes?

Example:

Button Value: Europe West --> Add Class EuWest to the current button class.

So it will show `<button class="buttonclass EuWest" value="Europe West">Europe West</button>`

Whenever the value changes to North America then for example, the class EuWest would remove and change to NorthAmerica.

**I want to do this because later on when searching Server Specific API's, I believe this is needed for something.**

Underneath the current code I have.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var regionDropDown = $('.region_dropdown_section'),
      regionButton = regionDropDown.find('button'),
      regionList = regionDropDown.find('.region_dropdown_content').children();

  $(regionList).on('click', function(e){
    var region = e.target;
    regionButton.text(region.text).val(region.text);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: url(../images/background/body_background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.SearchSummoners {
  margin: auto;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
background-color: #19A5D4;
color: white;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 12px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
}



/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.region_dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    max-width: 335px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.region_dropdown_section {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20%;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.region_dropdown_content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.region_dropdown_content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .region_dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.region_dropdown_section:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #1491BA;
}

.Searchbox_Summoners {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}


#SearchBox {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     width: 80%;
     background-color: white;
     height: 40px;
     float: left;
    }

        .region_dropdown_section {
         position: inherit;
         display: inline-block;
         max-width: 100% !important;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

#SearchInput{
  width: 92%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
 }

  /* Region Sprites */

.BR, .EUNE, .EUW, .JP, .KR, .LAN, .LAS, .NA, .OCEANIA, .RUS, .TURKEY{
 background: url(../images/icons/regions/regions.png) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.BR{
 background-position: -2px -2px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.EUNE{
 background-position: -2px -35px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.EUW{
 background-position: -2px -70px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.JP{
 background-position: -2px -105px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.KR{
 background-position: -2px -140px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.LAN{
 background-position: -2px -175px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.LAS{
 background-position: -2px -210px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.NA{
 background-position: -2px -245px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.OCEANIA{
 background-position: -2px -280px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.RUS{
 background-position: -2px -315px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}

.TURKEY{
 background-position: -2px -350px ;
 width: 26px;
 height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php define('DeniedAccessFiles', TRUE); ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
  <div class="SearchSummoners">
      <div id="SearchBox">
        <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
          <input id="SearchInput" value="Enter Summoners Name"  onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Enter Summoners Name') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter Summoners Name'; }"  type="text" name="SummonerName"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="region_dropdown_section">
        <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
        <div class="region_dropdown_content">
          <a href="?link=NA"><span class="NA"></span>North America</a>
          <a href="?link=EUW"><span class="EUW"></span>Europe West</a>
          <a href="?link=EUNE"><span class="EUNE"></span>Europe NE</a>
          <a href="?link=LAN"><span class="LAN"></span>LAN</a>
          <a href="?link=LAS"><span class="LAS"></span>LAS</a>
          <a href="?Link=OC"><span class="OCEANIA"></span>Oceania</a>
          <a href="?link=BR"><span class="BR"></span>Brazil</a>
          <a href="?link=KR"><span class="KR"></span>Korea</a>
          <a href="?link=JP"><span class="JP"></span>Japan</a>
          <a href="?link=TUR"><span class="TURKEY"></span>Turkey</a>
          <a href="?link=RUS"><span class="RUS"></span>Russia</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: You could use a `data` field on the `<a href="#" data-addclass="EuWest">Europe West</a>` or possibly do an object that stores an associative array to match up.

Comment: I've tried putting the data-addClass in the anchor, but that doesn't add a class to `<button class"dropbtn" value="Europe West">Europe West</button>`

Comment: Well you have make it grab the data, then use `$('element').addClass(value);` something like that. You can keep track of the current class so you can remove it before adding a new one.

Comment: I still don't understand. I'm not the best coder with Javascript. I'm still learning.
Basically the button needs to get a second class whenever a certan anchor (Example: Europe West) is selected. This class will be used later on to look for Region Specific API's and search in there

Comment: That last bit I am not 100% sure what you mean about the region specific thing. Do you need to persist this setting through the pages? If so you would do that when you submit the form (session assignment).

Comment: Let me explain quickly with this graph I made: https://gyazo.com/88a9adae684da9d518aee54fd49b57c2

In the search input, people will be able to type their In Game name, then they would need to select the Regional Server they play on. After pressing enter, based on the region selected in the dropdown button that you can see in the snipped. They would get the result from the Region Specific Server API, if that is more clear.

Comment: If you do this all with Ajax you would not need to persist that setting, it will just update the view. If you submit the form with page reload, you need to add a provision in there using php so your change sticks

Comment: Ok I kinda get it. Unfortunatelly I'm not good at Javascript/php and I definitely don't have experience with Ajax. I'll keep looking for examples/tutorials on doing what I asked. Hopefully someone else can help me. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this script work, you would need to change a few things. I would add a `data` field to the `<a href>` tags when they are clicked, the jQuery knows what to do. Then I would implement ajax so the page does not reload (otherwise you will need to do some PHP on this page to persist the setting when it reloads). See if this is what you are trying to do:

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/rtasdses/

**Form:**

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="SearchSummoners">
      <div id="SearchBox">
          <input id="SearchInput" placeholder="Enter the Summoner Name" name="SummonerName" />
      </div>
      <div class="region_dropdown_section">
        <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
        <div class="region_dropdown_content">
          <a href="#" data-addclass="selected"><span class="NA"></span>North America</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="blue"><span class="EUW"></span>Europe West</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="pink"><span class="EUNE"></span>Europe NE</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="green"><span class="LAN"></span>LAN</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="blue"><span class="LAS"></span>LAS</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="selected"><span class="OCEANIA"></span>Oceania</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="blue"><span class="BR"></span>Brazil</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="pink"><span class="KR"></span>Korea</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="blue"><span class="JP"></span>Japan</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="green"><span class="TURKEY"></span>Turkey</a>
          <a href="#" data-addclass="blue"><span class="RUS"></span>Russia</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="section2"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set the current class
    var currClass = false;
    // On click
    $('.region_dropdown_content > a').click(function(e){
        // Stop (just incase)
        e.preventDefault();
        // Assign current class
        var addClass    =   $(this).data('addclass');
        // Extract the text from the a tag
        var thisTxt     =   $(this).text();
        // If not empty, remove it
        if(currClass) {
            $('.dropbtn').removeClass(currClass);
            $('.SearchSummoners').removeClass(currClass);
        }
        // Now assign the current class to save
        currClass   =   addClass;
        // Add the extracted <a> text into the button tag to change name
        $('.dropbtn').addClass(addClass).text(thisTxt);
        // Add the class to the button
        $('.SearchSummoners').addClass(addClass);
        // this will send your request to whatever page
        // that will run your search
        $.ajax({
            // Url of the page that searches
            url:'/url/to/ajax/dispatcher.php',
            // This will submit to the above page using post
            data: {
                "search": addClass,
                "term": $("#SearchInput").val()
            },
            type: 'post',
            // This will place the response (html possibly) into a container
            success: function(response) {
                // Put html back into placeholder
                $('#section2').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS (I added just this part to the bottom to demonstrate):**

```
.selected {
    background-color: orange;
}
.blue  {
    background-color: red;
}
.pink  {
    background-color: pink;
}
.green  {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Let me explain quickly with this graph I made: gyazo.com/88a9adae684da9d518aee54fd49b57c2 In the search input, people will be able to type their In Game name, then they would need to select the Regional Server they play on. After pressing enter, based on the region selected in the dropdown button that you can see in the snipped. They would get the result from the Region Specific Server API, if that is more clear.

So basically whenever people select a specific region. I need to be able to get a class or something, so I can pull data from that regional Specific Server API

Comment: I have added the ajax part. You would send your post to the php page that contains the api and the response will post the data into the `<div id="section2"></div>`

Comment: Ok, that worked amazing already (Removed the Ajax bit for now, since I don't have the php api requests yet. But I stumbled upon a little problem now.
Basically I added ?link=Region into the href and now everytime I click a region, the region button doesn't change to the specific region I clicked. Which it should do.

Comment: So when you click the the link, do you want the page to reload or what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Basically this is the html `<a href="?link=NA"><span class="NA"></span>North America</a>` Whenever people hover the dropdown and click north america the link should change to [WEBSITE URL]?link=NA, but the page should not refresh and the dropdown button with standard value "Select Region" should change to "North America"

Comment: Alright I modified it, the text should change on the button

Comment: Didn't work for me, I updated the main question snippet with the current code I have. Wel it works, but the link in google chrome doesn't change (When clicking North America "WebsiteURL"?link=NA, When clicking EUWest "WebsiteURL?link=EU, .....

Comment: Yeah, it won't work because there is a `preventDefault()` on the action. This is where Ajax comes in, otherwise you are going to have to add php to this page to persist the choice, which you don't have. Once the page reloads with your choice in the query string (`?key=value`), you don't have any way in your code to save the setting. If you use Ajax, the page doesn't reload but you will pass on the choice into the ajax so it knows what to pull up next.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add something in your dropdown list such as `data-class="EuWest"` so JS can pick that up and append to your button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropbtn').on('click', function() {
    // Open the dropdown
    $('.region_dropdown_content').show();
  });
  
  $('.region_dropdown_content a').on('click', function() {
    // Add current location class to the button
    $('.dropbtn').attr('class', 'dropbtn ' + $(this).find('span').data('class') );
    
    // Close the dropdown
    $('.region_dropdown_content').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.region_dropdown_content {
  display: none;
}

.region_dropdown_content a {
  display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="region_dropdown_section">
        <button class="dropbtn">Select Region</button>
        <div class="region_dropdown_content">
          <a href="#"><span class="NA" data-class="NorthUS"></span>North America</a>
          <a href="#"><span class="EUW" data-class="EuWest"></span>Europe West</a>
          <a href="#"><span class="EUNE" data-class="EuNE"></span>Europe NE</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: That worked already. But my Region doesn't stay as the button value. In the main snippet the only thing that changes is the <a href="#"> changed to <a href="?link=region"> because  need this for future API requests.

Example: http://www.broadcasteralerts.com  (Since the ?link=region doesn't work on JSFiddle)